# React native Render Error how to solve this

Tags: reactjs, react-native

```
Render Error
Error: Text strings must be rendered within a <Text> component.
```

How to fix the above error in React Native? Here is my code:
Challenge1.jsx

```
import { View, Text, StyleSheet } from "react-native-web";
function Challenge1() {
    return (<View>
        <Text style={style.first}>
            Welcome to Thapa Technical Channel
        </Text>
        <Text style={style.second}>
            We love React native and i'm a subscriber of thapa technical channel
        </Text>
        <Text style={style.third}>
            Hii, My name is
        </Text>
    </View>)
}

const style = StyleSheet.create({
    first: {
        fontSize: 40,
        textAlign: "center",
        fontWeight: "bold"
    },
    second: {
        fontSize: 30,
        textAlign: "center"

    },
    third: {
        fontSize: 20,
        textAlign: "center",
        fontWeight: "bold"

    },
})
export default Challenge1;
```

Here is some information:

> Error: Text strings must be rendered within a  component.
>
> This error is located at:
> in div (created by Text)
> in Text (created by Challenge1)
> in div (created by View)
> in View (created by Challenge1)
> in Challenge1 (created by App)
> in RCTText (created by Text)
> in Text (created by App)
> in RCTView (created by View)
> in View (created by App)
> in App (created by ExpoRoot)
> in ExpoRoot
> in RCTView (created by View)
> in View (created by AppContainer)
> in RCTView (created by View)
> in View (created by AppContainer)
> in AppContainer
> in main(RootComponent)

Comment: I'm getting this same error, and I don't know how to solve this :(

Answer (score 3):

When you save code, an empty string is placed i.e. `<View> {" "} /View>`
You should have to remove this String.